# reuse SparkHadoopWriter in rdd.saveAsHadoopFile

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, garbage-collection

The Spark rdd.saveAsHadoopFile is very wasteful in that it generates a new SparkHadoopWriter on every write. We have a use case where the Spark job is backed up simply because gc on these Writers can not keep up with incoming stream.

Has any one done a reimplementation of this method where the SparkHadoopWriter is reused based on let's say which bucket the write target is. If I go in that direction, is there any architectural reason why the effort would fail?

Comment: Are you using spark streaming?  any demo code?

Comment: The code is just rdd.saveAsHadoopFile(s3path), but repeatedly due to new streaming batches coming in. You can see the write time gets slower and slower with time.

Answer (score 0):

`RDD.saveAsHadoopFile` is executed on the executors and in case we want to reuse the instance of `SparkHadoopWriter`, then we may need to perform serialization and  de-serialization each time the job is executed by the executors.

Although architecturally you can re-write the Spark-Core code or may be extend `RDD` and `PairRDDFunctions` and add code for serialize/ de-serialize and reuses the `SparkHadoopWriter` but in my perspective that may add more overhead as you need to serialize or de-serialize.

Though not sure about your Use Case but it is generally (though there are exceptions) good to have independent code units with no serialization (unless required) so that it creates objects and as soon as job finishes it destroys the objects. Though if required we can tune JVM to handle the Object creation/ deletion.

Comment: I am not sure its true about the need for serialization. I could for example, create a map of SparkHadoopWriters in the executor per container, and reuse them each time an RDD save is called. And as far as GC tuning, I posted another issue asking whether GC really helps in a streaming application, where new RDDs keep on coming. Larger young gen space may store more new RDDs, but eventually, its a race between incoming RDDs and GC speed to clean them up.